# Testng with Cucumber Maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng, browser-automation

I'm using Testng with Cucumber Maven. I have used the below approach for implementing Testng reporting with Cucumber Maven.

1. Feature file is created.
2. Runner class for Cucumber has been created by extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests class.
3. assertThat method is used in Glue code.
4. Test is triggered by running pom.xml

The test is executed, testng-results.xml file is also generated, however that does not include the assert step that has been mentioned.

Any help on what I'm missing.

Code snippet:

```
/*Runner Class*/
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-htmlreport", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"},
    features = {"src/test/resource"}
    )
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}


/*Glue Code:*/
@When("^Step$")
public void fnStep() throws Throwable {
    assertThat("Validation message", true);
```

Comment: This was just provided as an example. Consider that there is a line in the feature file like **When Step**

Comment: `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` is for JUnit. Don't mix JUnit and TestNG api.

Comment: have you used TestNG assert utility? please do not use "@RunWith tag" , it has no use in TestNG as pointed out by @Julien Herr , also you could look at this repo which explains how to use TestNG with cucumber. https://github.com/igniteram/testng-cucumber

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It worked when I removed @RunWith. Thanks much! :)